# intervention/image in config/app.php

Tags: php, laravel

[enter image description here][1]I have a problem in my file config/app.php
I downloaded intervention/image via "composer intervention/image"
And when I copied:

> Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class,

I had errors like this:

[image: 2]

Comment: What is the errors ??

Comment: Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class, -> undefined namespace Image;
'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class, -> undefined namespace Facades

Comment: Is the error just in the editor or at run time ??